# Material ui MaxwidthLG

Tags: css, material-ui, material-design

Hello I'm having a problem with material ui css. I tried to override it but still doesn't work. I want my full div to get the full page but this is happening.
[image]

I want it to take the full width. but I can't edit the muicontainer [image]

Answer (score 0):

in your CSS:

```
div.MuiContainer-root.MuiContainer-maxWidthLg.css-1qsxih2 {
width:100vw!important;max-width:100vw!important;min-width:100vw!important;
}
```

You might want to try using this selector instead (dropping the last class that seems to be generated each time):

```
div.MuiContainer-root.MuiContainer-maxWidthLg
```

Comment: doesn't work for me still has space on the side

Comment: ok, can you show the full HTML and CSS that is involved (in text, not images)

Comment: Hello I've added. body margin: 0, padding: 0, box-sizing: border-box. It works on my localhost but when published on Netlify it still doesn't take the full width.

Comment: Is it the same class every time? I see there is some random characters at the end that seem to be generated every time differently. That could explain it. Recheck that the class is exactly the same. Otherwise you could use javascript to inject the style and override anything else.